# Creating 1 record in 1 table from multiple records in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to populate a table with multiple records from another table.
I have a table which contains records of an employee's schedule.
Each record contains a single incident of a date and time for 1 employee:
Fields are:

```
ScheduleID = unique record identifier
ScheduleName = identifies the schedule
ScheduleLine = identifies the line on the schedule grid
Position = the schedule employee position filled (not necessarily the 
same as the employees postion)
ADP_ID = employee identifier
ScheduleBeginDay = what day of the week the schedule begins (usually 
Monday)
ShiftName = shift worked
ScheduleStart = date and time employee is scheduled to clock in
ScheduleEnd = date and time employee is scheduled to clock out
RecordActive = is record active or deleted
```

I need to convert this to look like a schedule grid in the application as well as in reports.
That is 1 line in the grid = up to 7 of the previous records (Monday – Sunday)

Sample input data:
ScheduleName    ScheduleBeginDay    ShiftName   ScheduleStart   ScheduleEnd Position    ADP_ID  ScheduleLine
Walk-In Center April Wk 1 2019  Monday  1st Shift   2019-04-01 07:00:00.000 2019-04-01 15:30:00.000 Mental Health Tech  10391   1
Walk-In Center April Wk 1 2019  Monday  1st Shift   2019-04-02 07:00:00.000 2019-04-02 15:30:00.000 Mental Health Tech  10391   1
Walk-In Center April Wk 1 2019  Monday  1st Shift   2019-04-03 07:00:00.000 2019-04-03 15:30:00.000 Mental Health Tech  10391   1
Walk-In Center April Wk 1 2019  Monday  1st Shift   2019-04-04 07:00:00.000 2019-04-04 15:30:00.000 Mental Health Tech  10391   1
Walk-In Center April Wk 1 2019  Monday  1st Shift   2019-04-05 07:00:00.000 2019-04-05 15:30:00.000 Mental Health Tech  10391   1
Walk-In Center April Wk 1 2019  Monday  1st Shift   2019-04-06 07:00:00.000 2019-04-06 15:30:00.000 Mental Health Tech  10244   1

Sample output data:
ScheduleLine    ScheduleName    ScheduleBeginDay    ShiftName   ScheduleStart   ScheduleEnd Position    ADP_ID  FirstName   LastName    ADP_ID  FirstName   LastName    ADP_ID  FirstName   LastName    ADP_ID  FirstName   LastName    ADP_ID  FirstName   LastName    ADP_ID  FirstName   LastName    ADP_ID  FirstName   LastName
1   Walk-In Center April Wk 1 2019  Monday  1st Shift   2019-04-01 07:00:00.000 2019-04-01 15:30:00.000 Mental Health Tech  10391   Arthur  Davis   10391   Arthur  Davis   10391   Arthur  Davis   10391   Arthur  Davis   10391   Arthur  Davis   10244   Eric    Harlin  10244   Eric    Harlin

The code below works but ONLY if there is a person in the position on day 1.
This is usually but not always the case.
the question is "How do i create 1 line of output for each line (position) on the schedule (as long as at least 1 person is working at least 1 day in that position at least one day during the week)?

```
declare @startdate as datetime
set @startdate = '4/1/19'

select 
   day1.ScheduleLine,
   day1.ScheduleName,
   day1.ScheduleBeginDay,
   day1.ShiftName,
   day1.ScheduleStart,
   day1.ScheduleEnd,
   day1.Position,
   day1.ADP_ID,
   Emp1.FirstName,
   Emp1.LastName,
   day2.ADP_ID,
   Emp2.FirstName,
   Emp2.LastName,
   day3.ADP_ID,
   Emp3.FirstName,
   Emp3.LastName,
   day4.ADP_ID,
   Emp4.FirstName,
   Emp4.LastName,
   day5.ADP_ID,
   Emp5.FirstName,
   Emp5.LastName,
   day6.ADP_ID,
   Emp6.FirstName,
   Emp6.LastName,
   day7.ADP_ID,
   Emp7.FirstName,
   Emp7.LastName
from @startDate
left outer join Schedules day1
left outer join EmployeeInformation Emp1 on Emp1.ADP_ID = day1.ADP_ID
left outer join Schedules day2 on  day2.ScheduleName = day1.ScheduleName 
and day2.ScheduleLine = day1.ScheduleLine and day2.ShiftName = 
day1.ShiftName and day2.Position = day1.Position and convert(varchar(10), 
day2.ScheduleStart, 101) = CONVERT(varchar(10), @startdate + 1,101)
left outer join EmployeeInformation Emp2 on Emp2.ADP_ID = day2.ADP_ID
left outer join Schedules day3 on  day3.ScheduleName = day1.ScheduleName 
and day3.ScheduleLine = day1.ScheduleLine and day3.ShiftName = 
day1.ShiftName and day3.Position = day1.Position and convert(varchar(10), 
day3.ScheduleStart, 101) = CONVERT(varchar(10), @startdate + 2,101)
left outer join EmployeeInformation Emp3 on Emp3.ADP_ID = day3.ADP_ID
left outer join Schedules day4 on  day4.ScheduleName = day1.ScheduleName 
and day4.ScheduleLine = day1.ScheduleLine and day4.ShiftName = 
day1.ShiftName and day4.Position = day1.Position and convert(varchar(10), 
day4.ScheduleStart, 101) = CONVERT(varchar(10), @startdate + 3,101)
left outer join EmployeeInformation Emp4 on Emp4.ADP_ID = day4.ADP_ID
left outer join Schedules day5 on  day5.ScheduleName = day1.ScheduleName 
and day5.ScheduleLine = day1.ScheduleLine and day5.ShiftName = 
day1.ShiftName and day5.Position = day1.Position and convert(varchar(10), 
day5.ScheduleStart, 101) = CONVERT(varchar(10), @startdate + 4,101)
left outer join EmployeeInformation Emp5 on Emp5.ADP_ID = day5.ADP_ID
left outer join Schedules day6 on  day6.ScheduleName = day1.ScheduleName 
and day6.ScheduleLine = day1.ScheduleLine and day6.ShiftName = 
day1.ShiftName and day6.Position = day1.Position and convert(varchar(10), 
day6.ScheduleStart, 101) = CONVERT(varchar(10), @startdate + 5,101)
left outer join EmployeeInformation Emp6 on Emp6.ADP_ID = day6.ADP_ID
left outer join Schedules day7 on  day7.ScheduleName = day1.ScheduleName 
and day7.ScheduleLine = day1.ScheduleLine and day7.ShiftName = 
day1.ShiftName and day7.Position = day1.Position and convert(varchar(10), 
day7.ScheduleStart, 101) = CONVERT(varchar(10), @startdate + 6,101)
left outer join EmployeeInformation Emp7 on Emp7.ADP_ID = day7.ADP_ID
where convert(varchar(10), day1.ScheduleStart, 101) = 
CONVERT(varchar(10), @startdate, 101)
order by day1.ScheduleLine
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and the expected output based on that sample data.  The table description you gave is a good start, but actual input and output samples provide details that table meta-data do not.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read up on how to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)  You may also benefit from [This article detailing what is considered necessary for a good SQL question](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/)

Comment: added sample data to question above

Answer (score 0):

This code works to create a weekly schedule from individual records.
In the actual live code the hard-coded strings (schedule Name, start date) will actually be populated from fields on the screen or calculated fields

```
--create a temp table to hold basic data for each line on the schedule
--this is referred to as day0 and will later be joined with data from days 1 - 7
CREATE TABLE #temp_dates (
    ScheduleName VARCHAR(MAX),
    ScheduleLine int,
    ScheduleBeginDay VARCHAR(MAX),
    ShiftName VARCHAR(MAX),
    Position VARCHAR(MAX),
    ScheduleStart datetime,
    ScheduleEnd datetime
);

--create 1 temp record for each line on the schedule and populate the basic data
insert into #temp_dates
(ScheduleName,ScheduleLine,ShiftName,Position,ScheduleBeginDay)
select distinct ScheduleName,ScheduleLine,ShiftName,Position,ScheduleBeginDay
from Schedules 
where ScheduleName = 'Walk-In Center April Wk 1 2019'
group by ScheduleName,ScheduleLine,ShiftName,Position,ScheduleBeginDay
order by ScheduleName,ScheduleLine,ShiftName,Position,ScheduleBeginDay

-- set date for start of weekly schedule 
declare @startdate as datetime
set @startdate = '04/01/2019'

--populate the schedule start and end times for each line
update #temp_dates
set ScheduleStart = @startdate + cast(Shifts.WorkTimeStart as datetime) , ScheduleEnd     = @startdate + cast(Shifts.WorkTimeEnd as datetime)
from #temp_dates
inner join Shifts
on shifts.ShiftName = #temp_dates.shiftname

--merge each temp table line with each days data for the week
USE CCAP
select 
   day0.ScheduleName,
   day0.ScheduleLine,
   day0.ShiftName,
   day0.Position,
   day0.ScheduleBeginDay,
   format(day0.ScheduleStart,'hh:mm') as StartTime,
   format(day0.ScheduleEnd,'hh:mm') as EndTime,
   day0.Position,
   day1.ADP_ID,
   Emp1.FirstName,
   Emp1.LastName,
   day2.ADP_ID,
   Emp2.FirstName,
   Emp2.LastName,
   day3.ADP_ID,
   Emp3.FirstName,
   Emp3.LastName,
   day4.ADP_ID,
   Emp4.FirstName,
   Emp4.LastName,
   day5.ADP_ID,
   Emp5.FirstName,
   Emp5.LastName,
   day6.ADP_ID,
   Emp6.FirstName,
   Emp6.LastName,
   day7.ADP_ID,
   Emp7.FirstName,
   Emp7.LastName
from  #temp_dates day0
left outer join Schedules day1 on  day1.ScheduleName = day0.ScheduleName and     day1.ScheduleLine = day0.ScheduleLine and day1.ShiftName = day0.ShiftName and     day1.Position = day0.Position and convert(varchar(10), day1.ScheduleStart, 101) =     CONVERT(varchar(10), day0.ScheduleStart,101)
left outer join EmployeeInformation Emp1 on Emp1.ADP_ID = day1.ADP_ID
left outer join Schedules day2 on  day2.ScheduleName = day0.ScheduleName and     day2.ScheduleLine = day0.ScheduleLine and day2.ShiftName = day0.ShiftName and     day2.Position = day0.Position and convert(varchar(10), day2.ScheduleStart, 101) =     CONVERT(varchar(10), day0.ScheduleStart + 1,101)
left outer join EmployeeInformation Emp2 on Emp2.ADP_ID = day2.ADP_ID
left outer join Schedules day3 on  day3.ScheduleName = day0.ScheduleName and     day3.ScheduleLine = day0.ScheduleLine and day3.ShiftName = day0.ShiftName and     day3.Position = day0.Position and convert(varchar(10), day3.ScheduleStart, 101) =     CONVERT(varchar(10), day0.ScheduleStart + 2,101)
left outer join EmployeeInformation Emp3 on Emp3.ADP_ID = day3.ADP_ID
left outer join Schedules day4 on  day4.ScheduleName = day0.ScheduleName and     day4.ScheduleLine = day0.ScheduleLine and day4.ShiftName = day0.ShiftName and     day4.Position = day0.Position and convert(varchar(10), day4.ScheduleStart, 101) =     CONVERT(varchar(10), day0.ScheduleStart + 3,101)
left outer join EmployeeInformation Emp4 on Emp4.ADP_ID = day4.ADP_ID
left outer join Schedules day5 on  day5.ScheduleName = day0.ScheduleName and     day5.ScheduleLine = day0.ScheduleLine and day5.ShiftName = day0.ShiftName and     day5.Position = day0.Position and convert(varchar(10), day5.ScheduleStart, 101) =     CONVERT(varchar(10), day0.ScheduleStart + 4,101)
left outer join EmployeeInformation Emp5 on Emp5.ADP_ID = day5.ADP_ID
left outer join Schedules day6 on  day6.ScheduleName = day0.ScheduleName and     day6.ScheduleLine = day0.ScheduleLine and day6.ShiftName = day0.ShiftName and     day6.Position = day0.Position and convert(varchar(10), day6.ScheduleStart, 101) =     CONVERT(varchar(10), day0.ScheduleStart + 5,101)
left outer join EmployeeInformation Emp6 on Emp6.ADP_ID = day6.ADP_ID
left outer join Schedules day7 on  day7.ScheduleName = day0.ScheduleName and     day7.ScheduleLine = day0.ScheduleLine and day7.ShiftName = day0.ShiftName and     day7.Position = day0.Position and convert(varchar(10), day7.ScheduleStart, 101) =     CONVERT(varchar(10), day0.ScheduleStart + 6,101)
left outer join EmployeeInformation Emp7 on Emp7.ADP_ID = day7.ADP_ID
order by day0.ScheduleLine,day0.ScheduleStart
```